# Sql Query to retrive data from table

Tags: mysql, sql

How to retrieve odd rows from the table?

In the Base table always Cr_id is duplicated 2 times.
[Base table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDnLE.png)

I want a SELECT statement that retrieves only those c_id =1 where Cr_id is always first as shown in the output table.
[Output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HQu0.png)

Just see the base table and output table you should automatically know what I want, Thanx.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please provide your query, you already tried? Thanks!

Comment: Please review the [SQL tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info)

Comment: Please publish sample data and expected output as TEXT together with what you have so far.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just testing min date should be enough

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(c_id int,cr_id int,dt date);
insert into t values
(1,56,'2020-12-17'),(56,56,'2020-12-17'),
(1,8,'2020-12-17'),(56,8,'2020-12-17'),
(123,78,'2020-12-17'),(1,78,'2020-12-18');

select c_id,cr_id,dt
from t
where c_id = 1 and
        dt = (select min(dt) from t t1 where t1.cr_id = t.cr_id);

+------+-------+------------+
| c_id | cr_id | dt         |
+------+-------+------------+
|    1 |    56 | 2020-12-17 |
|    1 |     8 | 2020-12-17 |
+------+-------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```

Comment: this is correct question check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/65339189/14843356

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for could be "partition by", at least if you're working on mssql.
(In the future, please include more background, SQL is not just SQL)

https://codingsight.com/grouping-data-using-the-over-and-partition-by-functions/

I have an old query lying around, that is able to put a sorting index on data who lacks this, although the underlying reason is 99.9% sure to be a bad data design.

Typically I use this query to remove bad data, but you may rewrite it to become a join instead, so that you can identify the data you need.

The reason why I'm not putting that answer here, is to point out, bad data design results in more work when reading it afterwards, whom seems to be the real root cause here.

```
DELETE t
FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY column_1 ,column_2, column_3 ORDER BY column_1,column_2 ,column_3 ) AS Seq
FROM Table
)t
WHERE Seq > 1
```