# Sql query for retrieve data of senders only with a specific c_id where senders and receivers data in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

t is a table which contains sending and receiving date of courier along with their respective customer, Customer ID is c_id, Courier Id is cr_id , sanding or receiving date is dt.

```
create table t(c_id int,cr_id int,dt date);

insert into t values
(1,56,'2020-05-15'),(56,56,'2020-10-17'),
(1,8,'2020-05-17'),(56,8,'2020-12-17'),
(123,78,'2020-01-17'),(1,78,'2020-12-18');
```

I am inserting customer first which sends a courier and below that which receives a courier if any order placed successfully.

Here I want to retrieve data of senders only with a specific c_id?

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: Hi Varun. What is your question. Please try and be a bit more descriptive.

Comment: zWouldn't you just use `where c_id = ?`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `ROW_NUMBER` window function as follows:

```
select * from
(select t.*, row_number() over (partition by cr_id) as rn
  from t)
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It goes in the same sens as @Popeye, but order by is needed to get 1st value:

```
select dt, cr_id from (
  select t.dt, t.cr_id, 
  row_number() over (partition by cr_id order by cr_id ) rn
  from t) t1
where rn = 1
order by cr_id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=266a34e3c5183430e5308d82ad90c248